# Error installing android application

Tags: android

I have an android application that use to external JARs, i have begin to seem this error when try to deploy to a device or emulator.

```
[2012-12-07 00:06:17 - testsuite] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
[2012-12-07 00:06:17 - testsuite] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-12-07 00:06:17 - testsuite] Launch canceled!
```

And the logcat output

```
12-07 00:06:16.251: E/dalvikvm(404): Out-of-order method_idx: 0xffff then 0x1
12-07 00:06:16.251: E/dalvikvm(404): Trouble with item 3934 @ offset 0x6aead0
12-07 00:06:16.251: E/dalvikvm(404): Swap of section type 2006 failed
12-07 00:06:16.261: E/dalvikvm(404): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
12-07 00:06:16.281: E/dalvikvm(404): Optimization failed
12-07 00:06:16.301: W/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.xxx.testsuite-1.apk'  --- status=0xff00, process failed
12-07 00:06:16.301: E/installd(34): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-  cache/data@app@com.xxx.testsuite-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
```

The error seems related to one of the external JARs, if i move of this JAR to the eclipse project it works (but i don't want to do that)

any ideas how to track down this issue?

Comment: tell us what jar did you use...

Comment: is a JAR file not public available, is a testsuite for a product in develop.

Comment: @Jose Did you fix this jose?

Comment: @RethinavelPillai If I recall this correctly it was due to a very large JAR file that I create with all my test cases.